# ¿Cómo quitar los comentarios de un json en php?

Tags: php

Buen día comunidad,

Estoy tratando de insertar un json a mi base de datos mysql, sin embargo, me doy cuenta que mi objeto tiene 2 comentarios en el encabezado y eso me esta generando ruido al hacer el insert, cuando se los quito me deja insertar, sin embargo, quisiera quitárselos desde php ya que estoy consumiendo una api y no podría quitárselo manual. me pudieran decir si existe alguna función o algo que pueda omitir esas dos lineas del json?

mi codigo que ocupo para el insert

```
function obtenerOrdenes(){
    $curl = curl_init();
     $url = "http://dwww.test.com/apiRest";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$httpheader);
    $resultado =curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $ordenes = json_decode($resultado,true);
    $ordenes = $ordenes["value"];  
     $ordenesTest = array();
     if($ordenes){
       foreach($ordenes as $orden){
         foreach($ordenes as $orden){
```

json

```
// 20220315102642
// http://dwww.test.com/apiRest

{
  "@odata.context": "www.test.com/apiRest",
  "value": [
    {
      "Document_ID": "CO02472",
      "Card": "L90",
      "Status": "Ready",
      "Full_Name": "Lalo"

    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: En la variable $resultado también te aparecen los comentarios? y el json_decode te convierte a array? Si en $resultado tienes los comentarios simpre podrás eliminarlos con una expresión regular o simplemente eliminando todas las líneas antes de la primera llave

Comment: si, el json_decode lo convierte en un array

Comment: Lo que no veo es como lanzas el insert, porque si puedes leer el archivo y convertirlo en array podrás recorrer el array y añadir los valores sin problema al insert.

Comment: // 20220315102642
// http://dwww.test.com/apiRest
Solo quiero omitir estas dos lineas para que el insert lo haga sin problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
$json = '
// 20220315102642
// http://dwww.test.com/apiRest

{
  "@odata.context": "www.test.com/apiRest",
  "value": [
    {
      "Document_ID": "CO02472",
      "Card": "L90",
      "Status": "Ready",
      "Full_Name": "Lalo"

    }
  ]
}';

$arrayLineas = explode(PHP_EOL, $json);
$iniciar_guardado = 0;
foreach ($arrayLineas as $linea) {
    if ($iniciar_guardado == 0) {
        if (preg_match('/^\{$/', $linea)) {
            $iniciar_guardado = 1;
            $guardado = [$linea];
        }
    } else {
        $guardado[] = $linea;
    }
}
echo implode("\n", $guardado);
```

## **Explicación corta**

Básicamente lo ponemos en un array y luego lo vamos recorriendo hasta que encontramos el inicio del objeto, y entonces lo vamos guardando en una nueva array hasta que lo sacamos con un implode de nuevo.

## **Explicación al detalle**

Cogemos el json (en tu pregunta se corresponderia con tu variable $resultado que contiene todo el *string*) y lo almacenamos en un *array* de líneas, y para ello usamos la función [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) y usamos como delimitador la constante predefinida [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php) para no tener problemas de codificación en la plataforma que lo estés ejecutando.

```
$arrayLineas = explode(PHP_EOL, $json);
```

- Inicializamos una variable `$iniciar_guardado` que usaremos en plan booleano que nos indicará, más adelante, cuando podremos almacenar los datos.

```
$iniciar_guardado = 0
```

- Recorremos el *array* línea por línea:

```
foreach ($arrayLineas as $linea) {
```

- Y si la variable $iniciar_guardado aún tiene el valor 0 entramos en el condicional:

```
if ($iniciar_guardado == 0) {
```

- Dentro de este condicional buscamos la línea que sabemos que nos define el inicio del objeto, es decir, que empieza por `{` y no contiene nada más.  Lo cual expresamos con la expresión regular siguiente:

```
'/^\{$/'
```

quedando finalmente así la instrucción completa:

```
if (preg_match('/^\{$/', $linea)) {
```

Fijarse que para ello estamos usando la función [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) que está especificamente diseñada para la búsqueda de expresiones regualares.

- Si se cumple el anterior condicional, es decir, si se encuentra la línea que empieza por `{`, entramos en el condicional y cambiamos el valor de `$iniciar_guardado` por 1.  De este modo, y gracias al condicional anterior a este, ya no tendremos que volver a pasar por aquí en el siguiente ciclo.

```
$iniciar_guardado = 1;
```

- Acto seguido iniciamos el guardado de lo que será el json de salida correcto, y lo hacemos así:

```
$guardado = [$linea];
```

porque de este modo estamos haciendo tres cosas: 1) Lo iniciamos 2) Le decimos que es un array y 3) Incluimos la línea que contiene la llave `{` que será el inicio del objeto json.

- Después cerramos este condicional, y no hace falta decirle nada más, ni poner un `else` para nada, porque todo lo que pueda ocurrir antes de encontrar la llave `{` no nos importa ni vamos a guardarlo (es decir, esquivamos las lineas de los comentarios y lineas vacias previas a la definición inicial del objeto).

```
}
```

- Con esto ya hemos terminado la primera parte del condicional inicial, pero ahora viene su condición `else` que se corresponde con lo que tiene que hacer si la variable `$iniciar_guardado` ya no equivale a 0:

```
} else {
```

- ¿Y que tiene que hacer cuando la variable $iniciar_guardado ya no equivale a 0?  Pues simplemente ir agregando el resto de lineas hasta el final al array `$guardado` que hemos creado mientras buscábamos la llave `{`:

```
$guardado[] = $linea;
```

- Y ya podemos ir cerrando tanto este primer condicional del todo, como tambien el bucle que nos irá iterando las líneas contenidas en el array `$arrayLineas`:

```
    }
}
```

- En este punto ya debemos tener la nueva variable de array denominada `$guardado` rellena con todas las líneas. Pero necesitamos que no sea un array de líneas, sino un string de nuevo, para luego poderle pasar el `json_decode`, por lo tanto tenemos que volverlo a implosionar respetando de nuevo los saltos de linea. Y lo hacemos así:

```
echo implode("\n", $guardado);
```

Bueno, en este caso simplemente lo muestro, pero se podria haber hecho así tambien:

```
$json = implode("\n", $guardado);
```

para que luego, y siguiendo el hilo de la pregunta, lo pudiera manejar asignándolo así:

```
$ordenes = json_decode($resultado,true);
```

Y yasta.

Comment: Gracias, lo voy a probar y te cuento

Comment: @geek_root He ampliado la explicación de mi respuesta por si habia algo que no entendieras. Al aceptar mi respuesta entiendo que ya lo has probado y te ha funcionado bien, no?  Saludos!